# How to reset inputs based on radio button clicked

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons that show parts of a form when clicked as the page is blank when initialised. The parts of the form are located in two different divs. The code below takes care of that very well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='btnyes']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.hidemyforms").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
        $("div.showsubmit").show();

});
```

});

**Radio buttons**

```
     <input type="radio" name="btnyes" id="btnyes" value="getmytimeregular" />Yes
     <input type="radio" name="btnyes" id="btnyes" value="getmytimetaken" />No
```

I'm trying to target the div #getmytimetaken and reset the inputs with the following code when the div #getmytimeregular is visible if the user had selected any previously.

```
    $("#getmytimetaken").hide().find("input").val("");
```

Also if the div #getmytimeregular is visible i need this code not to run as it targets the div #getmytimetaken and ceates errors.

```
$('.ft4').change(function() {
    var goo = $('.ft4[selectedIndex!=0]').length;
    if (goo >= 1) $('.ft4[selectedIndex=0]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else $('.ft4').removeAttr('disabled');
```

});

Comment: btw, you have two controls with the same id (id="btnyes"). dom element can have only unique id attribute value

Comment: They have different values...

Comment: they can have different values, but the ID attribute must be unique within document. think about, how can you access to the element with custom id if there are several such elements? the browsers parse such document well, but result will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't undestand exactly what you are asking, but it seems to me you are trying to do something based on the visibility of a div. In this cas you could use:

```
if($("#getmytimetaken").is(':visible')){
///code to execute if the div is visible
$("#getmytimetaken input:radio").removeAttr('checked')
}else{
///code to execute if the div is not visible
}
```

Comment: it's not firing up..for some reason. it hides the whole form

Comment: This was just an example (you should put some logic behaind it) i just don't understand exactly what you are trying to do: can you post an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here's the fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/5nTsk/4/
My goal is to make it simple for the user.

If the user selects **Yes**, then selects **No** and then changes an option within the **No** portion then goes back to **Yes** portion i need to reset the **No** value to the default.

Thanks